# Having Trouble with Mutable Array to load sections in a Table View from Plist

Tags: iphone, arrays, plist, tableview

Plist loaded in AppDelegate with following structure:

Root ----> Dictionary

Test Item ----> Array

Item 1 ----> Dictionary

HeaderTitle ----> String ----> Section 1

Items ----> Array

Item 1 ----> Dictionary

FirstName ----> String ----> Any Name

SecondName ----> String ----> Another Name

CellIcon ----> String ----> Icon.gif

View ----> Number----> 2

Item 2 ----> Dictionary

FirstName ----> String ----> Any Name 2

SecondName ----> String ----> Another Name 2

CellIcon ----> String ----> Icon2.gif

View ----> Number----> 2

I have a TableViewController.m that  requires me to put the above plist structure in a table view that has 5 sections. The problem is I can't get that data to show in the described sections of my table view. I am getting confused in writing a mutable array to accomplish this task. I am already using an array to control the different levels (views) in my table but I am having trouble adding the mutable array to control the sections of the table. The code I have is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (CurrentLevel == 0) {
    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
    [tempArray release];

    TheAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (TheAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"SampleArray"];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Main";

          }
      else 
    self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;   
          }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; 
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [menuSections count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSDictionary *menuSection = [menuSections objectAtIndex:section];
return [menuSection objectForKey:@"HeaderTitle"];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
NSArray *menuItems = [[menuSections objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Items"];
return [menuItems count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks wrong with your code, are you sure your arrays have data in them when those methods are entered?

Comment: Yes..My plist has the data in them. Although this code compiles, my app crashes when going to the tableview. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You set tableDataSource in viewDidLoad, but how does menuSections get built from that?   I think we need more source.